# Proxychains + nmap = segmentation fault

Tags: penetration-test, nmap, proxychains

If I try the `sV` (service detection) flag in nmap run via proxychains (socks5 server) it appears to give me a segmentation fault message:-

```
root@kali:~# proxychains nmap -n -sT -Pn X.X.X.X -p 22,80,222,10000 -sV
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)

Starting Nmap 6.46 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-07-25 16:40 BST
Segmentation fault
```

If I remove `-sV` or limit my scan to certain ports it is OK.

Is this a bug in nmap and/or proxychains and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I can't reproduce with 6.46 and proxychains 3.1. Please include output of `nmap --version` and run your command with `-d` for debugging output. Do you have the same problem if you run directly without proxychains?

Comment: we cant tell you which is causing the seg fault. Read your `/var/log/messages`

Comment: Can you please try using this newer and more-complete version of proxychains -- https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng/ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known problem with the classic Proxychains program, which is not currently maintained. [Proxychains-NG](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng) is a good alternative; it is actively maintained, and does not suffer from this particular crash.

Comment: It's good to know about this Proxychains-NG alternative, thank you. A side note, I found the quick workaround in the other answer by tireksz helpful in squelching the issue in situations where employing NG may not be viable, and where proxy_dns is not required. All of it great info.

Answer (score 9):

For me, the solution was to disable the DNS through socks:

In the `/etc/proxychains.conf` file, just comment the line `proxy_dns` by adding a `#`:

```
# proxy_dns
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be useful to identify why the program crashes. I had the same problem when NSE was initiated. Looking at [dmesg](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html) showed me the following:

```
[158085.716905] nmap[28540]: segfault at 6 ip b6489234 sp bf89ee6c error 4 in liblua5.2.so.0.0.0[b6483000+36000]
[158389.020572] nmap[28761]: segfault at 6 ip b7380234 sp bf9d61bc error 4 in liblua5.2.so.0.0.0[b737a000+36000]
[158523.581566] nmap[28860]: segfault at 6 ip b73d9234 sp bffbb9bc error 4 in liblua5.2.so.0.0.0[b73d3000+36000]
```

Which seems to indicate that the problem wasn't directly in proxychains or nmap but in liblua. Updating it to the latest version fixed this bug for me.