# does Nmap automatically use proxychains if configured?

Tags: nmap, proxychains

I have configured my proxy chains in `/etc/proxychains.conf`. Then when just run `nmap` or even `nc` without the `proxychains` prefix, it automatically uses the proxy chains and routes the traffic through the proxies. I have verified that there are no alias for both the commands. Is this the expected behaviour? Does Nmap checks the `/etc/proxychains.conf` automatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use nmap through proxychains?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122561/how-to-use-nmap-through-proxychains)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Basically when I have the environment variable `LD_PRELOAD` set in the shell (`export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.3`), the Nmap automatically uses the proxychains. Otherwise it behaves normally.

Comment: Yes, that's what `LD_PRELOAD` is designed to do